# Windows 10 v1809 use custom WIM for "Reset this PC"

Tags: windows, reset, recovery

In Windows 7, 8 and 8.1, after capturing a well-audited image as OS restoration image, I use run this command in my running OS to instruct WinRE to use this image when resetting:

```
reagentc.exe /setosimage /path R:\Recovery\WindowsRE\install.vim /index 1
```

Then when I reboot the computer to recovery environment and select "Reset this PC" (resetting from WinRE, not Settings -%gt; Reset), it wipes out the whole `C:` partition and applies that image, in a manner similar to

```
DISM.exe /Apply-Image /ImageFile:R:\Recovery\WindowsRE\install.wim /Index:1 /ApplyDir:C:
```

---

However, this no longer works with Windows 10. Even if I tell WinRE to use my custom image with REAgentC, it just resets to a fresh Windows install, completely ignoring my prepared `install.wim`.

Any solution?

---

Related: [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/875a594d-b01c-40ec-926b-be01f12494d3/how-to-use-custom-imageinstallwim-recovery-in-windows-10?forum=win10itprosetup)'s a thread with the *identical* question on Microsoft TechNet, with a stupid moderator posting a few non-answers.

Comment: When you initiate "previous versions of Windows", which versions are you talking about exactly, there shouldn't have been any changes with regards to how Windows 10 Reset image works (between individual versions of Windows 10).

Comment: @Ramhound Unsure about exact versions, but I can assure that it worked well in 7, 8 and 8.1. Maybe also Win10 build 10240 and 10586, but not recent versions.

Comment: Windows 7 did not have a Reset functionality.  How Reset works between Windows 8 and Windows 10 is indeed different.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for that information. Now I want to know how to make it work in latest Windows 10...

Comment: `/setosimage` can still be used despite what the documentation on [reagentc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/reagentc-command-line-options) indicates. So from within the WinRE, run the command `reagentc /info` and verify the correct image is being used.  Update your question with the necessary information to answer your question.  In order to submit an answer myself, I would need a VM, which I don't have access to currently.   If this question is unanswered when I do have access I will answer it.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh yeah, I'll make an edit now.

Comment: In order for somebody else to answer your question, providing the relevant information from `reagentc /info`, might be helpful to them.   This should be done within Windows 10 instead of WinRE.  I am pretty sure the reason, the correct image is not being used, is because your doing the Reset from within WinRE which would have a different recovery image configured.Do the Reset from within Windows 10 and/or create a new WinRE image that uses to the correct image.

Comment: @Ramhound That probably qualifies as an answer and I have a feeling that it might be the correct one. Mind posting it as answer instead of comment?

Comment: @Ramhound I'll do some experiments later and come back when I have updates. That's a precious tip!

Comment: Only after I verify it.  I won't be creating an answer that explains how to create a custom WinRE image.  I don't have time for that but will verify, WinRE uses a different image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 uses different system for PBR - Push-Button Reset. And the option `/setosimage` [was removed from the ReAgentC program.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/reagentc-command-line-options)

## Why

Before in 8 and 8.1, (or Win 7 if you provided your own restore tool in Win Recovery) the a complete image was made. After restore, you end up with the exact state as it was when the computer was manufactured, or when you yourself created the recovery WIM.
This means you will need to go through possibly years of updates again. Half-yearly updates would take hours to finish.

Microsoft came up with dusted down User State Migration Tool (USMT). The resulting file is still WIM, but it's not a complete disk image. It's a "saved state". Contains all files and registry entries, which are not part of the Windows itself. There is no Windows in the image.

## How

When you do Reset, Windows will check integrity of each package (and its files) of the active Windows installation. If it finds corrupted file, it shall download that package and do a fix (never had myself opportunity to see this in action), than it will save current drivers and put them aside. It will rename Windows to Windows.old and "reinstall" clean Windows using packages from previous one. Then drivers are applied and lastly your USMT.PPKG (actually renamed WIM) file.

You'll end up with a system state as it was when you (or factory) created the recovery, but with updated Windows. And the Recovery file itself is only 200-300MB big.

If you include Office or some other Apps and have expensive disk space, there is a feature called Single Instance, which will link real files to this PPKG file.

[The process of creating PBR is described on MS docs page.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/deploy-push-button-reset-features)

## What changed

If the above link is TL;DR and you already are familiar with the process from Win8.1,
what has changed is that

- instead of DISM /capture you run: `N:\ScanState_amd64\scanstate.exe /apps /config:"$PSScriptRoot\ScanState_amd64\Config_AppsAndSettings.xml" /ppkg C:\Recovery\Customizations\USMT.ppkg /o /c /v:13 /l:C:\ScanState.log`
  The scanstate is on ADK and you need WinPe files from it too to make it run. Update the paths as needed, but this part is fixed: C:\Recovery\Customizations*.ppkg
- There is no separate Recovery partition and the rest of files, which were needed before: ResetConfig.xml and diskpart scripts are needed only if you plan on nonstandard disk partitioning or ResetConfig scripts. If so, those files goes into C:\Recovery\OEM
  You don't use ReAgentC to register your ppkg file. All files in C:\Recovery\Customizations*.ppkg are applied after Reset.
- You run scanstate (the capture) from running OS (best to use Audit mode). It's not possible to do a capture from WinPe.

But I think it might be possible to create an additional option in WinRe, to restore using a full disk image WIM file and have both options work in parallel. I'm just exploring this, might come back here and edit my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

The `/setosimage` switch does still work under Windows 10, you can register your customized image location with it.

But attempting to Reset My PC using a custom image saved here won't work on Win10 as before.

The options presented to Fully Reset will essentially clear your OS back to OOBE defaults as if you've installed it fresh, similar to the Apple or Android reset methods.

So there is no major benefit to using the WinRE environment for the purposes of Resetting the PC if what you're after is the Push Button Reset like Win8.1 had that could recover a customized capture of your OS.

Instead, You can perform DISM operations to capture and restore your OS image from a bootable USB or inject these scripts into the WinRE environment to avoid external devices altogether.

Just remember that it's risky to capture and restore an OS image that keeps the WinRE within its volume.  You should register WiNRE in its own partition.

Windows 10 installs tend to put the default Recovery partition before the OS, sometimes before the EFI partition, so it will be challenging to stretch the size of the Recovery partition.  You need to stretch its size in order for it to host the WinRE environment, and that's fairly difficult without 3rd party tools, and that still may leave you without a bootable system.  It may be best to create a separate Recovery volume of ample size after the OS, as is often recommended anyway.